# Do you HAVE to use the CommandArgument property with a LinkButton which is inside of a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The link button only sets some value as true and does nothing else.

When I run the code the LinkButton's event just won't fire!

In my aspx page I got this LinkButton inside of a repeater with CommandName="SetDefault", some ID, runat property. That's it.

In my code, inside of myRepeater_Itemcommand(), I got this

```
if (e.CommandName == "SetDefault")
{
    Users obj = new Users();
    obj.IsDefault = true;
}
```

[EDIT] I resolved it myself. It was a silly mistake. "l" was missing from "SetDefault" in my aspx page :/

Comment: Does the button really HAVE to be inside the Repeater if it's just setting a static value? Be careful when you say "it only sets some value as true".

Comment: it might seem silly, but if you answer your question yourself, you should *still* post an answer and accept it.  That way it gets removed from the queue.  Glad you figured it out though! :)

Comment: @Kirk:: oh I didn't know we could do that..accept my own answer ie..thnx for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly spelling mistake in the Command Name. I resolved it myself.